# Torque control with H-Bridge via direction pin

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, h-bridge

Using the LMD18200 (H-Bridge) and the [LM3524D](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2524d.pdf) (PWM regulator) I should design
a torque regulation. I've found a circuit in the [LMD18200 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmd18200.pdf#page=14&zoom=130,-174,759) which uses the current feedback to adjust the PWM.

The question bothering me is **why should I connect the PWM output to the direction 
pin** and not to the PWM pin itself? Is this only some good practice, doesn't it matter or is it required?

From my point of view connecting to the PWM pin should work fine since the current is always measured the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Pins 3, 4 and 5 are interchangeable with no loss or deterioration in timing performance. Minimum input pulse width for all these inputs is defined as 1us (page 4 of the data sheet).

If you look at the logic output truth table on page 8 you can use these logic inputs in any combination you want to achieve the desired output functionality.